# making a glossary with wordpress

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, functions, filters

I know that there are glossary plugins in the wordpress repository. This plugins normally searches glossary terms in post content and adds a link to it. But i have not found one, that search and replace terms in custom post types.

Because of this i am trying to make my own glossary plugin. if you know about a plugin that make this, please tell me.

My code search custom post type posts titles in the post content and replace it with a link. The problem is that it make the replace in all the text, including a title atributte of a links, and i dont want to replace it by a link in this cases.

what can i do to it doesn`t replace when is link atributte text?

This is my code:

```
function reemplazar($cadena){

    //get glossary posts type posts
    $args = array(
        'showposts'   => -1,
        'category_name' => 'glosario',
        'post_type' => 'glosario',
    ); 
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

    //Create an array with post title in keys and post link in a value
    $reemplaza = array();
    foreach ($posts_array as $posts) {
        $reemplaza[get_the_title($posts->ID)] = '<a href="' . get_permalink($posts->ID) . '" title="' . $posts->post_content .'">' . get_the_title($posts->ID) . '</a>';
    }

    //create an array with array keys and add a regex for search terms that are before a dot, coma o white spaces
    $patterns = array_keys($reemplaza);
    $pattern_final = array();
    foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
        $pattern_final[] = '/(?<=\s|^)' . $pattern . '(?=\s|\.|\,|$)/i';
    }

    //replace in the post content words that are a glossary term by a link to glossary
    $cadena = preg_replace($pattern_final, $reemplaza, $cadena, 1);
    return $cadena;
}

//do reemplazar function when post content display
add_filter('the_content', 'reemplazar');
```

Comment: This seems a little more like generic programming challenge with text manipulation and might be better asked at [so].

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% follow your question, but I wrote this tutorial on [creating a glossary with a custom taxonomy](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/424/alphabetical-posts-glossary/). Maybe it will be useful to you.